# PHP Create dynamic Images with GD

Tags: php, image, crop, image-resizing, resize-crop

i wrote a function for create & crop images with PHP. i load a list of Images (over 500 images) dynamically create and crop these images in a foreach loop.

i tried this with the new crop function in PHP >= 5.5:

```
resource imagecrop ( resource $image , array $rect )
```

this function is buggy, since it adds a black line at the Bottom of the created Image. but i can create so many images as needed in a foreach loop using this function.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67447&edit=3

my Function using **imagecrop** :

```
function createAndSaveImage($imagePath, $targetName){
    $imagesize = getimagesize($imagePath);
    $imagewidth = $imagesize[0];
    $imageheight = $imagesize[1];
    $imagetype = $imagesize[2];
    switch ($imagetype){
        case 1: // GIF 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($imagePath);
            break;
        case 2: // JPEG 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
            break;
        case 3: // PNG 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($imagePath);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    $rect = array();
    $rect["x"] = 230;
    $rect["y"] = 140;
    $rect["width"] = 40;
    $rect["height"] = 30;
    $thumb = imagecrop( $image , $rect );
    if( $imagetype == IMAGETYPE_PNG ){
        imagepng($thumb, $targetName,9);
    }else{
        imagejpeg($thumb, $targetName,100);
    }    
    return true;
}
```

now instead of **imagecrop** i tried the same using **imagecopy** OR **imagecopyresampled**.

i call  my function in a foreach loop. it creates goog croped images(no black lines at bottom), BUT it breaks allways after 300 items (sometime more).

my Function using **imagecopy** OR **imagecopyresampled:**

```
function createAndSaveImage($imagePath, $targetName){
    $imagesize   = getimagesize($imagePath);
    $imagewidth  = $imagesize[0];
    $imageheight = $imagesize[1];
    $imagetype   = $imagesize[2];
    switch ($imagetype){
        case 1: // GIF 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($imagePath);
            break;
        case 2: // JPEG 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
            break;
        case 3: // PNG 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($imagePath);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    $thumbwidth = 40;
    $thumbheight = 30;
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbwidth, $thumbheight);
    imagecopy($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 230, 140, $imagewidth, $imageheight);
    //imagecopyresampled( $thumb, $image, 0, 0, 230, 140, $imagewidth, $imageheight, $imagewidth, $imageheight );
    if( $imagetype == IMAGETYPE_PNG ){
        imagepng($thumb, $targetName,9);
    }else{
        imagejpeg($thumb, $targetName,100);
    }
    imagedestroy($thumb);
    return true;
}
```

any idea why? is it a RAM / Cache issue?

**UPDATE [phpInfo]:**

```
max_execution_time         0    30
max_file_uploads          20    20
max_input_nesting_level   64    64
max_input_time            -1    -1
max_input_vars          1000    1000
memory_limit            128M    128M
```

first Value : **Local Value**

Second Value: **Master Value**

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a max-execution-time problem. Try adding `set_time_limit(0);` to the top of your script, or change the value of `max_execution_time` in php.ini.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i added set_time_limit(0); to the top of my script. but it still not working, take a look to my update in the Question please!

Comment: How long does it take to time out? It could still be a timeout issue (sometimes you cannot override that setting). Or it could be memory. Try adding `echo memory_get_peak_usage(true) . "<br/>";` in your `foreach` loop and post the greatest number shown.

Comment: the greatest number of memory_get_peak_usage(true) is 5505024

Comment: What about the amount of time? How long does it take to die? Are there any error messages on screen or in your error logs?

Comment: no errors or any warnings, it dies/breaks after 14.9 seconds

Comment: 14.9 is a suspicious timeout. It could be that (1) a different php.ini is overriding your settings (PHP doesn't always display this correctly) or (2) some part of your script overrides it if you are using any third-party code. Also, just a hunch, how are you building the list of files to process? You may be missing some based on their extensions or other criteria. Finally, have you actually verified that `getimagesize` is returning only the types you handle (1, 2, and 3)? (It's probably better to use the defined constants here, by the way, not magic numbers).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57115/discussion-between-rami-q-and-ed-cottrell).